# conditional validation for single text box

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I having a MVC3/Razor form with a dropdown and a single text box. Dropdown has 2 options to choose either OrderID or ClerkName.

If user choose OrderID, then I want to accept only numbers [0-9] into textbox and if user choose ClerkName, then I want to accept only characters [a-z, A-Z] into textbox.

I want here jQuery validaton..please help me in this direction.

Here we need to check validation in both case,  1. on form load and 2. on DDL selction change.....please help.

```
  @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div id="mainP">
        <div>
            @Html.DropDownList("SearchBy", new[] {  new SelectListItem { Text = "Order ID", Value = "OrdId" },
                                                    new SelectListItem { Text = "Clerk Name", Value = "ClerkName" } })
            <br />
            @Html.TextBox("SearchedText", ViewData["SEARCHED_TEXT"] == null ? "" : ViewData["SEARCHED_TEXT"], new { @class = "search_text_area" })
            <br />
        </div>
        <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" />
    </div>

}
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {



    });

</script>
```

Comment: thnx a lot Bala R to edit code section....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you really want to:  clear the input on selection change (since by your validation rules, its no longer valid) and validate on submit, not form load.

```
$(function(){
  // Get a reference to the controls we'll re-use throughout the program
  var searchedText = $("#SearchedText");
  var searchBy = $("#SearchBy");

  // Determine the validation regular expression
  function GetValidationRegex(){
    if (searchBy.val() == "OrdId")
      return /^[0-9]+$/;
    else
      return /^[a-zA-Z ]+$/;
  }

  // Define our on change handler
  function SearchByChangeHandler(){
    // Clear the input
    searchedText.val("");
  }

  // Bind the handler
  $("#SearchBy").change(SearchByChangeHandler);

  // Bind to the form submit to validate
  $("form").submit(function(){
    // Get the text
    var value = searchedText.val()
    // If no text, error case 1
    if (!value){
      alert("A value is required...");
      return false;
    } 
    // If doesn't match the validation expression for the current selection
    // this is your error case
    else if (value.match(GetValidationRegex()) == null){
      alert("Regex doesn't match...");
      return false;
    }

  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to create a custom validation rule:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("numbersXorLetters", function(value, element) {
    var isValid = false;
    if($("#SearchBy").val() == "OrdId")
        isValid = /^[0-9]*$/.test(value);
    if($("#SearchBy").val() == "ClerkId")
        isValid = /^[a-zA-Z]*$/.test(value);
    return this.optional(element) || isValid;
}, "Invalid value");
```

And then applying this like so:

```
$("#SearchBy").rules("add", {
  numbersXorLetters: true
});
```

Hope this helps. Cheers